# PySimpleGUI: Why cant I close the program here?

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Why does the program not check for the Event sg.WINDOW_CLOSED ?

First I check for the event "OK" and output the entered Name

But the following check for closing the window does not work here.

Why cant there be more than one event-checks in the event-loop?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
# Define the window's contents
layout = [[sg.Text("What's your name?")],
          [sg.Input(key='-INPUT-')],
          [sg.Text(size=(40,1), key='-OUTPUT-')],
          [sg.Button('Ok'), sg.Button('Quit')]]

# Create the window
window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout)

# Display and interact with the Window using an Event Loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Ok':
        print(event)
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Hello ' + values['-INPUT-'] + "!")
    # Why cant I check for closing the program here?    
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == None:
        print(event)
        window.close()
```

Comment: A statement `break` missed to break from event loop.

Comment: After which line should I insert the break statement?

Comment: The window closed, so it should break from it's event loop. Add it after you call `window.close()`.

Comment: sorry, does not work for me:
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Ok':
        print(event)
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Hello ' + values['-INPUT-'] + "!")
    # Why cant I check for closing the program here?    
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED or event == None:
        print(event)
        break
window.close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window closed, so it should break from it's event loop. Add `break` after you call window.close().

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Quit'):     # break from event loop to call `window.close()
        window.close()
        break

    elif event == 'Ok':
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Hello ' + values['-INPUT-'] + "!")
```

or break from event loop and call `window.close()`.

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    print(event)

    if event in (sg.WINDOW_CLOSED, 'Quit'):     # break from event loop to call `window.close()
        break

    elif event == 'Ok':
        window['-OUTPUT-'].update('Hello ' + values['-INPUT-'] + "!")


window.close()
```